# When i am running recipe second time i dont want to start the service second time

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, test-kitchen

when i have added this recipe first time i want to run the service but whenever i am trying to deploy other recipe, I don't want to run this service again

I have tried to add condition as creation of new file for guard

```
service 'mapr-zookeeper' do
  action :start
end
```

Comment: If the service is already running, chef won't start it again. This concept is called "idempotency".

Comment: If I say restart how can I guard for second time

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Maybe add your full code. Usually, you don't have to add `only_if`/`not_if` guards, esp. regarding services.